# Unclear type inference for mapped types with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

In a project, where I struggle to create correct typing.

I have a function that destructures the result of a type map. While destructuring the type inference is somehow lost.

```
interface Foo { field1?: string; field2?: string; }
interface Bar { field3?: string; field4?: string; }

type Name = 'foo' | 'bar';
export type NameValueMap<N extends Name> = 
  N extends 'foo' ? Foo : 
  N extends 'bar' ? Bar : 
  never;

type TransformerHelper<N extends Name> = { transform?: () => NameValueMap<N> };
type TransformerMap<N extends Name = Name> = { [T in N]: TransformerHelper<T> };

const transformerMap: TransformerMap = {
  foo: {},
  bar: {},
};

function getValue<N extends Name>(name: N) {
  return transformerMap[name];
}

function doTransform<N extends Name>(name: N) {
  const { transform } = getValue<N>(name);

  // do some stuff

  return transform?.();
}

// problem: typescript is somehow confused when inferring the type
const M1 = doTransform('foo');             // type is Foo | Bar
const M2 = doTransform('bar');             // type is Foo | Bar

// expected: typescript should infer the types of doTransform() in the same way as with getValue().
const N1 = getValue('foo').transform?.();  // type is Foo
const N2 = getValue('bar').transform?.();  // type is Bar
```

Check out a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-p2xwvh?file=index.ts) of this problem. You can see the problem, when you hover over the consts: `M1`, `M2`, `N1`, `N2`.

How it is: [image: inference tooltip]

How it should be: [image]

I tried different implementations of `doTransform` but I was only able to make it work when I explicitly assign the type to the returned value, which I'd like to avoid.

```
function doTransform<N extends Name>(name: N) {
  const { transform } = getValue<N>(name);

  // do some stuff

  return transform?.() as NameValueMap<N>;
}
```

I'd really be happy for some help. I have no clue why typescript is not inferring the value correctly and how I could change my types so that typescript does a correct inference.

Comment: The compiler cannot do this sort of inference; it decides to eagerly resolve certain uses of generic expressions; see [this comment on a similar github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47013#issuecomment-985872616) You can painstakingly try to express what the types would have to be, but you need to use type assertions to say that they are, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrGl2m), which isn't any better than `as NameValueMap<N>` like you're doing.  I'm happy to write up an answer unless you think I'm missing something here.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz I'd be happy for an answer here, so I can mark this as a solution.

Comment: Uh, I don’t even remember this because it happened three months ago. Generally speaking you should stick around after asking a question on SO to respond to comments. As it is now I don’t know if I will look at this further.